# Does MySQL compress() and uncompress() consumes much ram/hardware from the server?

Tags: mysql, sql, compression

Recently I've found these two `MySQL` functions [compress](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [uncompress](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) and I'm planning to use it in my database to compress some `xml` files (around 40 million ~ 600GB+) to reduce my database size. Unfortunately, I didn't found anything about performance and ram/hardware usage from those functions.

How would it be in terms of performance and server ram usage performing hundred/thousands of queries like these per minute?

```
SELECT cast(uncompress(document) AS char(10000)) 
  FROM documents;
```

Comment: Idk, but some considerations: you could also compress the whole table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html. They also suggest you could compress the content in the application outside of mysql.

Comment: Seems to use zlib as the backend, so similar requirements as zlib would have (but you'd really need to grok the code to see what settings it uses). Best way to answer that is to benchmark it yourself on the hardware you intend to use.